# Generate -10V to 2V from 12V to 0V

Tags: fpga

I am generating square pulse 3.3V to 0V from FPGA  and through a level shifter (12V to 0V). The output we require is -10V to 2V. Any suggestion? We are wondering to use comparator now or is there any better way to do it?

Setup details:

1. Current power used on the board: 1.8, 3.3, 12, 2, -8, 8, 5, -5, -10 and 20V
2. Our signal running on 62.5 kHz range(12V).
3. we connected the circuit to capacitive load (10 nF)

Here is what we tried.

We had a try on Op-amp, I just learned a lesson picking right op-amp based on how fast our signal frequency.

And we also tried on the circuit below:

Circuit:

[image: Circuit]

Waveform:

[image: Waveform]

But there some spike on rising and falling edge.

Comment: Add more details: who fast is the signal, what delay and raise/fall time is acceptable? What load is applied to the -10..2V signal? What power lines do you have a available, maybe -12V or -15V?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what power supply rails you have. If you have a -12V power rail then you could amplify the 3.3Vp-p signal to 12Vp-p and apply a dc offset to centre the output to -4V. This can be done with an op-amp quite easily but, choosing the op-amp depends on how fast the 3.3Vp-p signal is. If it is at 1MHz or above, a little more care has to be taken choosing the correct op-amp to reproduce adequate rise and fall times.

Comparators can be OK but to get the accuracy of the final output signal means the comparator needs exact supply voltage rails of -10V and +2V. I think the op-amp linear amplifier route is likely to be more successful.

Comment: Thanks for help. seem we have -10V and 2V on board. we will try the comparator method.we going to use LM358, just got 1 question can we supply -10V to Vcc and 2V to GND? sorry asking this. or else we can invert it in fpga.

Comment: No that won't work - most op-amps don't get close to being able to swing their outputs to the positive and negative supply rails - either use a comparator or a rail-to-rail op-amp.